# How to add annotation based on current location when buttons is clicked?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I tried to add an annotation in my map when I click the button. I have written some codes but I am not getting any annotation based on my current location.

```
  @IBAction func addPressed(_ sender: Any) {
  guard let location = self.locationManager.location else {
        return
    }

    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.title = "Flooded"
    annotation.subtitle = "Reported on 12/10/2018 8:50 AM"
    annotation.coordinate = location.coordinate

    self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

Comment: You need to add `viewForAnnotation ` by conforming to `MKMapViewDelegate`

Comment: where shall i pass the code viewForAnnotation

Comment: @iOSArchitect.com can you please rewrite the code?

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your view controller and also make sure to assign delegate to self for mapView in viewDidLoad()

**Update**: As dicsussed in comments, replace your complete view controller code with the code below.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var add: UIButton!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapView.delegate = self
        locationManager.delegate = self

        checkLocationServices()


    }

    func setupLocationManager () {
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    }

    func checkLocationServices() {
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            setupLocationManager()
            checkLocationAuthorization()

        } else {

        }
    }

    func checkLocationAuthorization () {
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {

        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        case .restricted:
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Location Services disabled", message: "Please enable Location Services in Settings", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(okAction)

            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return

        case .denied:
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Location Services disabled", message: "Please enable Location Services in Settings", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(okAction)

            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return

        case .authorizedAlways:
            break
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            mapView.showsUserLocation = true // this will bring the blue dot on map
            centreZoomviewUserLocation()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        @unknown default:
            break
        }
    }


    func centreZoomviewUserLocation () {
        if let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate {
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location, latitudinalMeters: 10000, longitudinalMeters: 10000)
            mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        }
    }
    //MARK:- Button pressed

    @IBAction func addPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let location = self.locationManager.location else {
            return
        }

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = "Flooded"
        annotation.subtitle = "Reported on 12/10/2018 8:50 AM"
        annotation.coordinate = location.coordinate

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

        }
    }


}


extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let newPin = MKPointAnnotation()
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: center, latitudinalMeters: 10000, longitudinalMeters: 10000)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        newPin.coordinate = location.coordinate
        mapView.addAnnotation(newPin)

    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        checkLocationAuthorization()
    }

}


extension ViewController : MKMapViewDelegate {

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        guard annotation is MKPointAnnotation else { return nil }

        let identifier = "Annotation"
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)

        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            annotationView!.canShowCallout = true
        } else {
            annotationView!.annotation = annotation
        }

        return annotationView
    }
}
```

Comment: still not working

Comment: @Priya have you added `yourMapView.delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad()` ?

Comment: I have written your code inside the IBaction.. yes i have mentioned the delegate in viewdidload

Comment: @Priya extensions are declared outside the class. add this at the end of your file. after the last `}` in your file.

Comment: I did sir. problem is its showing annotation but I want to click the button then annotation should be triggered on map

Comment: replace your `mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)` to this in @IBAction `DispatchQueue.main.async {
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
}`

Comment: i did . But still its not working

Comment: you are doing something wrong. Update all your code here in question if you can.

Comment: wait I am doung

Comment: I am unable to do.. I am uploading a new question... please enter my profile & see the question'

Comment: I am u able to add that also

Comment: @Priya replace your complete code with the one i updated above.